# Implementing an unusual sequence as an infinite list in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, sequence, lazy-sequences

I have two elements as the beginning of the list [1, 2]

This unusual sequence is that it replicates the digits in the number of digits of a certain type that follows the three elements. For example, after 1 and 2, we would have another 2, followed by two 1's.
The first few elements of the desired list would yield

[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2] because

```
1  2   2  1 1   2  1  2   2  1   2   2
```

where the previous digits represent the length of the mini-sequences of the same digit.

So far I've tried using the `replicate` function for repeating the same digit based on an element earlier in the list.

```
selfrle :: [Int]
selfrle = 1 : 2 : [x | a <- [0..], let x = replicate (selfrle !! a) (selfrle !! (a + 1))) ]
```

The problem is I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of your description of the sequence you want to generate.

Comment: turns out it's an infinite sequence of symbols {1,2}, which starts with `[1,2, ...]`, and is a sequence of run lengths from its own RLE encoding: `ks == ([1,2] ++) . drop 2 . map fst . rle $ ks`.

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that unusual as it appears in the OEIS at https://oeis.org/A000002 and is named there as the Kolakoski sequence. There they even give a Haskell program by John Tromp dated 2011:

```
a = 1:2: drop 2 (concat . zipWith replicate a . cycle $ [1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you can do it get your types right.  `replicate` builds a list, so the `x` in your list comprehension has the type `[Int]`, and the entire list comprehension is a list of all the `x` values, and its type is `[[Int]]`.  You cannot use a list of *lists* of `Int` as the tail of a list, when the first two elements are `1` and `2`.  The types just don't match: you need to decide whether this is a list of `Int`, or a list of *lists* of `Int`.

Based on your description, I suspect you want to fix this by flattening the list comprehension using `concat`, like so:

```
selfrie = 1 : 2 : concat [x | a <- [0..],
                              let x = replicate (selfrie !! a) (selfrie !! (a + 1))]
```

If you try this, you won't get the list you described.  I don't know how to help with the next part, and that's because I don't understand your description of the desired list.  This isn't a programming question so much as a specification question, so perhaps you could go back to the original source and see how it's explained there?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295842/implementing-an-unusual-sequence-as-an-infinite-list-in-haskell#comment102973591_58295842)

Answer (score 0):

We can write this slightly more elegant than [@DanD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58296076/67579), by using an extra variable `b` on which we "tie a knot":

```
a :: [Int]
a = 1 : 2 : b
    where b = 2 : concat (zipWith replicate b (cycle [1, 2]))
```

We here thus first yield `1 : 2 : b`, with `b` that starts with `2` and then the concatenation of the replicates of `b` with an endless list with `[1, 2, 1, 2, …]`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems concise and very efficient but hard to reason with especially if you are a beginner and neglect Haskell's laziness.

We can rephrase it like

```
a = 1:2:2: (concat . zipWith replicate (drop 2 a) . cycle) [1, 2]
```

We must remember that `a` is just a semi constructed list like `1:2:2:?: ... ?:[]` and we start using it just by discarding the first two items `(drop 2 a)` which leaves us with `2:?: ... ?:[]` to apply to `zipWith replicate` and this is sufficient for us to run our logic indefinitelly. Keep in mind `2:?: ... ?:[]` is a list to be calculated just like `cycle [1,2]`. The availability of the initial item `2` enables the next item to be calculated and then the next item and then the next and so forth.

This is a beautiful pattern in Haskell to generate infinite lists if you know the initial items. Take for instance the fibonacci series

```
fib = 1:1: (zipWith (+) fib (tail fib))
```

All you need to do is to tweak your mindset to think like `fib` is already there but not yet calculated.

**Another Approach with State Monad:**

However, i believe that the given Kolakoski series could also be a good case study to learn the State monad. Let's see if we can get the same performance..?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

invert :: Int -> Int
invert = (+1) . (`mod` 2)

rle :: Int -> State Int [Int]
rle n = state $ \s -> (replicate n s, invert s)

kolakoski :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
kolakoski ps s = ps ++ kolakoski xs i
                 where (xs,i) = runState (mapM rle ps >>= pure . concat) s
```

- We have an `invert` function when fed with `1` gives `2` and when fed with `2` gives `1`.
- `rle` takes an `Int` type and returns a `State` type, a function which takes the state and replicates it by `n` and returns the replicated list along with a new state, `invert s`. So our state alternates like `1,2,1,2...` along the way.

However when tested with ghci (`:set +s`), while both show linear time complexity, this takes 10 times longer to finalize. Anybody care to comment..?